# Facebook Graph API get url_tags for each ad

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I would like to get the url_tags for a corresponding ad. I know that I can get the url_tag by **/adcreatives** api. But this would require me to make a call for each ad separately, and I exceed the rate limits. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Go via the `/adcreatives` edge of the ad account, and use Field Expansion syntax? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#field-expansion

Comment: (That will not necessarily help regarding Rate Limits though, because those are, at least in part, about what _amount_ of data you request. Using a different way to get more data making less API requests, does not automatically fix any issues that result from the sheer amount of data to begin with.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But  I managed to fins an alternative, which was to use the creative field in ads and create a mapping between ads and creative